# blender.stackexchange.com is the only site that does not reflect user profile changes

Tags: bug

The following is a minor issue.

When I open my user profile page on `blender.stackexchange.com`, I fond my old contents. The other sites have reflected the latest changes of my user profile.

[image]

However, when I press the edit button, this site loads the latest version as follows.

[image]

I don't think it is due to propagation delay between sites. Is it  a bug?

Comment: I see your old content as well. Only a CM or Admin would be able to tell, I have no clue

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: OK. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you have a history of account merging? Your account is also not shown on [the network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/6961806/artificial-stupidity?tab=accounts).

Comment: @AndrewT.: I think I have no such a history of account merging.